# Write on screen directly on top of everything

Tags: batch-file

Is there any way to make some huge text appear on screen on top of everything?
something as shown below.

[image]

I know I can use Rainmeter but i need something that can be used in batch files.

Comment: it might be useful to include what you're trying to do rather than how you want to solve it.

Comment: Rainmeter with the illustro theme can read a text file periodically, for example each minute. If your batch modify the text file it will be shown on screen.

Comment: Batch could call a WPF dialog to grab focus, but not like the above. You can just "create" text on its own without a supporting window etc.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'm making a batch file that does some tasks when the user connects to a specific network, what i want is to show a large text on the screen when all tasks in the batch are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, if you use PowerShell! I wrote this script for you:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.TransparencyKey = $form.BackColor
$form.WindowState = 'Maximized'
$form.FormBorderStyle = 'None'
$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font ($label.Font.FontFamily, 200)
$label.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromKnownColor('Green')
$label.AutoSize = $true
$label.Text = 'Text!'
$label.Add_Click({$form.Close()})
$form.Controls.Add($label)
[Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($form)
```

You can change the `Text!` and `Green` values to whatever you prefer. When that script is invoked, a massive text will be shown on top of everything and will only go away when you click on the text. Basically, it creates a transparent form and puts a large label on it.

Save that script as a `.ps1` file. To enable script execution on a system, see the Enabling Scripts section of [the PowerShell tag wiki](https://superuser.com/tags/powershell/info). You can run that script from a batch file like this:

```
powershell.exe -File '\path\to\script.ps1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **no**, without external, not natively installed programs.
You could start a message-box which would grab quite a bit of attention, but that is written in VBScript, which is native to Windows, but isn't Batch.

Comment: It turns out you can accomplish this with a bit of PowerShell. See my answer :)

Comment: I stand corrected... on one of the things I said, great answer by the way!